# Could someone explain references in Java via pointers and references?

Tags: java, c++

Lots of people have asked if Java is "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value", yet I feel I haven't gotten a good explanation of how Java actually stores references and how it dereferences them when called.

Would anyone be able to explain what happens when you have something like, say,

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        Object a = new Object();
        Object b = a;
        Object c = b;
        bar(c);
    }
    public static void bar(Object obj) {
        obj = new Object();
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

in terms of pointers?

How is the JVM actually referencing and dereferencing objects and references?

I'm guessing it's semantically equivalent to the semi-pseudo C++ code:

```
int main() {
    Object *a = new Object;
    Object *b = a;
    Object *c = b;
    bar(c);
    return 0;
}
void bar(Object *tempObj) {
    tempObj = new Object; 
    //changes address of a copy of the ptr arg
    cout << std::to_string(*tempObj) << endl;
}
```

(I know there is no `Object` class in C++ and that `to_string` isn't defined for every class like it is in Java, but for the sake of example I think it helps illustrate the concept.)

Am I correct? Bottom line: what's going on under the hood? I'd like a more explicit answer.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/jvms8.pdf

Comment: Take the top answer from this search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+pass+by+value. This question has been asked already many, many times on stackoverflow.

Comment: If you want to look under the hood, read the [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/)

Comment: What Patricia said, but [JVM8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/).